# center align a rotated movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a dynamically created movie clip which contains a text field.

I then rotate the move clip by 20 degrees.

I then want to center the clip on the stage. But the width and height readings, along with positioning x and y makes it position in the wrong place, which I guess is due to the registration point.

Is there a work around to this?

This is `flash 8`, `as2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center align the text field to the movie clip. If you are dynamically setting the text and the text field is auto sizing, remember to re-apply the center alignment of the text field:

```
//Assuming mc is your MovieClip instance and tf is the child TextField instance
var tf = mc.tf;

//Reading the width and height of the TextField will remain accurate and unchanged by it's parent's rotation as it's rotation remains zero.
tf._x = -(tf._width / 2);
tf._y = -(tf._height / 2);
```

If you keep the movie clip at the center of the stage, the text field will appear to stay center as well. Regardless of the rotation of the movie clip.

Answer (score 0):

code to make a mc with reg point in middle

```
var mc:movieclip = new movieclip
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0);
mc.graphics.drawRect(-1,-1,2,2);
mc.graphics.endFill();
```

code to put this center reg point mc in the middle of the stage

```
 mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
 mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
```